# How can I understand what the speaker is saying in his Aussie accent?

Tags: accent

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2UnMxR3IM)

The Aussie says, "Now..." [at 0:45](https://youtu.be/FH2UnMxR3IM?t=45) in the video.  Then again [at 1:53](https://youtu.be/FH2UnMxR3IM?t=113), what is he saying?

Which movies should do the job for understanding the Aussie accent clearly?

Comment: At 1:53, I believe the commentator says “he's knocked the game on its head”.

Comment: At :45, I think he says "bad shoulder and all".

Answer (score 3):

Australian accents can be [roughly divided into three groups](http://dialectblog.com/2011/07/10/types-of-australian-accents/).

- Broad accents, such those of Steve Irwin, and Paul Hogan
- General accents, used by most people, such as Kylie Minogue
- Cultivated accents, which sound almost like British accents, For example Cate Blanchett, and some Liberal party MPs

For most visitors, understanding the "general" dialect is most important, as most speakers are able to "code switch" and move from the broad accent to a general accent, if necessary.

There are some great Aussie movies "Pricilla Queen of the Desert", "Muriel's Wedding" and of course "Crocodile Dundee". More recent films include "Snowtown" and "Animal Kingdom"

Comment: I would also recommend some Australian podcasts, such as Hamish and Andy. It helps understand the pronunciation of some words in Australian English. Besides being fun to listen to it.